# Do the elements of a one-dimensional array have to be of primitive data type in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, types, primitive-types

**My computer programming teacher claims that in Java:**

> The elements in a one-dimensional array must be of primitive data type

**I've done hours of research but I can't find *any* statements to back up this claim.**

I know that I can make arrays of objects in Java. *Even the CLI arguments are passed into the program via a `String` array.*

Her justification is that `String[]` can be viewed as a multi-dimensional array of characters. I can understand this but I cannot see how this could apply to all objects.

She goes on to say that one-dimensional arrays cannot hold objects because arrays that hold objects become multi-dimensional.

I cannot understand how arrays of `Object`, `Integer` and `Scanner` can be multidimensional.

**I'm very confused right now, am I missing anything?**

Comment: *The elements in a one-dimensional array must be of primitive data type*, no no no no . . . NO! That's completely wrong.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, I've worked with Java for 4 years and have never even heard of this. I'm just posting this here as my entire class accepted this without raising any flags and I was wondering if maybe I've been missing something the whole time...

Comment: it definitely wrong. According to this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html . you can search for "array of Object" on that page.

Comment: Your teacher needs a teacher to teach her Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array can store elements of **any type** - a primitive `int` or `long` or `float`, a wrapper `Integer`, an object like `String`, `Person`, `Animal`, etc.

You must understand that any **Array** data structure is meant to be stored as **contiguous** block of memory, be it of anything, **but** of the same data type.

- With *primitive* types, it is the contiguous block of actual values,
  i.e., *int* array will have each int occupy 4 bytes, array of *long*
  will have each occupy 8 bytes, and so on.
- With an array of *objects* (String, Person, Animal) the array will store the *reference variable* (this is not a pointer like in C++) to all of those objects and those references will be in contiguous block.

Like if you have `Person p1 = new Person()` and `Person p2 = new Person()` and store in an array `Person[] arr = {p1, p2}`.

The *arr* will have the references *p1* and *p2* stored in the memory and when you traverse the array you can reach the actual *Person* object, which in itself can be a mixture of many String or int values (like id, name, address, etc). So this still gives you the efficiency of an array.

This doesn't mean that *arr* becomes multi dimensional in any way.

You can read about this at many other places in more detail and get back to your teacher.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is absolutely wrong.

For example, you could have an array of `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal[] numbers = { BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ONE };
```

Or an array of `Person`:

```
Person[] people = { new Person("John", 20), new Person("Jane", 21) };
```

With `Person` being:

```
class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    // TODO getters
}
```